# To find the value of $y(3/2)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Let $y(x)$ be a continuous solution of the IVP:

$$\left\{\begin{eqnarray}y'+2y &=& f(x)\\y(0) &=& 0\end{eqnarray}\right.$$

Find $y(\dfrac{3}{2})$.

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{$0\leq x\leq 1$} \\
0 &\text{$x>1$}
\end{cases}$$

**My try :**

I solved it in two cases:

Case 1:$x\in [0,1]$ taking $y^{'}+2y=1$ and using $y(0)=0$ on solving I get $y=\dfrac{1-e^{-2x}}{2}$

case 2:$x>1$ taking $y^{'}+2y=0$; I get $\ln y=-2x+c$ where $c$ is a constant.

what should I do now?

Comment: You might start by exponentiating both sides of case 2 to get $y=Ce^{-2x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task is to glue the functions together at $x=1$.

As commented by @amd it might be better to first write the function in the second case as $y=Ce^{-2x}$. Then, for the function to be continuous at $x=1$, you should find $C$ so that the expression to the left of $x=1$ and the expression to the right of $x=1$ agrees at $x=1$, i.e. you should solve the equation
$$
\frac{1-e^{-2\cdot 1}}{2}=Ce^{-2\cdot 1}.
$$

In the figure below, you find the expression to the left in blue. To the right of $x=1$ you see several curves, corresponding to different values of $C$. The red ones correspond to wrong values of $C$, since for these there is a jump at $x=1$. The green one is the correct one.

[image: limning]

Once, you have calculated the value of $C$, you just have to insert $x=3/2$ into $y=Ce^{-2x}$.

Comment: Very nice use of diagram

Comment: very good and useful one

Answer (score 0):

Since $y(x)$ is continuous solution, so for calculating the value of $C$ we use the condition $y(1)$ from $y(x)=\frac{1-e^{-2x}}{2}$.
 we get $C= \frac{e^{2}-1}{2}$,
put this $C$ in $y(x)=Ce^{-2x}$, and calculating $y(3/2).$
 i.e., $y(3/2)=\frac{e^{-1}-e^{-3}}{2}$,
that is $y(3/2)=\frac{\sinh (1)}{e^{2}}$

Comment: good answer +1 @Deepa